# parameter validation in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am working on a java app that utilizes PreparedStatement.

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE (FIELD1='firstFieldValue' OR FIELD1='' or 'firstFieldValue'='');
```

firstFieldValue is a parameter. And it is necessary to check that its value is empty in SQL.

I created a prepared statement with the following parametrized SQL:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE (FIELD1=? OR FIELD1='' or ?='');
```

and I set values as follows:

```
preparedStatementInstance.setString(1, this.firstFieldValue);
preparedStatementInstance.setString(2, this.firstFieldValue);
```

This way does not work. Execution fails.

I think the prepared statement SQL is wrong.

How can I fix the SQL for prepared statement for this case?

Comment: Could you try putting the "?" on the right-hand side?

Comment: good point, I will check now, thank you

Comment: This way does not work, but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check it in java.

```
if firstFieldValue.equals("") 

then SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM MYTABLE 

else  

SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE (FIELD1=? OR FIELD1='');

preparedStatementInstance.setString(1, this.firstFieldValue);
```

Comment: `And it is necessary to check that its value is empty in SQL.` The better question would be WHY it is necessary to check in SQL.

Comment: The actual SQL is more complex than I specified. I am just wondering is it possible to use passed parameter in this way: `?=''`

Comment: Well. From common case, it is rare to do it in SQL.Is there any benefit to do it in SQL?

Comment: I understand that it is not an elegant way. Ok, I will find a workaround. Thank you.

Comment: These checks are fit to do it in java. THere is no reason to let DB to do it.

Comment: If the check is complex and related with columns in the table, then I will consider define a custom function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no 'i think it is wrong' in executing sql's, either it is correct and it executes the query or the sql is wrong and you get an sqlexception

If it fails you should provide the forum with the stacktrace so we dont have to mindread.

what do you mean with 'empty'?
 empty as a empty string or as null in the db

Comment: Empty string. Just wanted to check the parameter that it is empty.